# Differential Equations - Method of Undetermined Coefficients for products of polynomials and sines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

Consider

$y''+y= 2x \sin (x)$

I have the solution for the homogeneous equation. Now i am trying to guess a particular solution for: $2x \sin (x)$

My first guess was: $(Ax+B) \cos x + (Cx +D) \sin x$
but i end up with the system:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
-2A & +2B& =0\\ 
2C =0&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Then my quess was: $(Ax^2+xB) \cos x + (Cx^2 +xD) \sin x$ but that leaves me with:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
-Ax & -B & +4C & =0\\ 
2A & 2D & =0 & \\ 
-4A & -Cx & -D & =0\\ 
-2B & 2C & =0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I feel something is wrong.

So, i would like to know if mi guess is ok at least, then i will try to figure out how to arrange the equations in order to have something useful.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your first system of equations?

Comment: It seems to me that it says that $A=B$, $C=0$ and $D$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @Joel The solution should be $y(x) = c_2 sin(x)+c_1 cos(x)-1/2 x^2 cos(x)+1/2 x sin(x)$ (from wolframalpha). I dont see how to get something similar from my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last guess is true but your calculations are incorrect
The final equation should give 
$$2A+2D=0\\-2B+2C=0\\-4A=2\\4C=0$$
Thus $C=B=0,A=-D=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: How i know exaclty that the first guess is not correct for the solution?. If the system have arbitrary values for some variables is something i can trust?

Comment: Comparing every term in your solution with the homogenous solution, we find that both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are repeated in the particular solution, so we multiply them by $x$, repeat this step till all terms are different